# VS2010 - Navigate To shortcut shows "Recent Files", not Navigate To

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

All the documentation suggests that ctrl+comma should bring up the navigate to dialog.  When I perform that keystroke in VS2010 I get a list of "Recent files" instead.  Under the "Edit" menu, "Navigate To" doesn't display a keyboard shortcut.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation probably refers to profile settings different from what you've chosen.  You can customize them by going to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and set the keybinding you want.  You can also reset your settings to one of the defaults (or a previously exported set) from Tools -> Import and Export Settings.

Comment: thanks!  Reshaper overwrote that shortcut, even through I'm using the VS Keyboard scheme.